# Как отправить сообщения юзерам при старте бота Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Допустим, создал я бота. Хочу, чтобы обособленно от готовых хендлеров, бот отправлял всем пользователем подготовленное сообщение. Допускаю, что это можно сделать, во время перезапуска бота
Пробовал этот способ, ничего не вышло и ничего не понял:

````
from aiogram import Bot

token = 'token'
bot = Bot(token)


async def gg():
    while True:
        await bot.send_message(id, msg)
        asyncio.sleep(10)


asyncio.run(gg()) ```
````

Comment: Так погодите-ка, вы хотите при запуске бота отправлять всем юзерам сообщение о том, что бот запущен, я правильно понял?

Comment: Да,  всё верно   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна бд с юзер айди для того чтобы сделать это. У aiogram есть встроенные способы сделать что-то при старте бота и при завершении это on_startup и on_shutdown.
Вот примерный код как это должно работать.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncio

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def on_startup(_):
    arr = []  # абстрактный массив с юзер_айди
    for user_id in arr:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="Бот запущен!")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: не понял строчку

arr = []  # абстрактный массив с юзер_айди

Comment: ну так что в нем непонятного? Абстрактный потому-что суть пытаюсь обьяснить. Вы должны сами его заполнить с вашей бд. То есть вы перебираете вашу бд и вытягиваете юзер айди. Всё.

Comment: Бд сделал, не умею и не понимаю. Как в arr= выбрать весь столбик user_id

Comment: В таком случае посмотрите гайды по вашей бд, поверьте это очень легко

Comment: Не могу найти ответ 2 часа. Увы даже в чатах разработчик, кроме смешков и упреков, что я вообще взялся за это, не нашёл.

Comment: https://pythobyte.com/python-sqlite3-tutorial-database-programming-riqdhwx9z-fafd14f8/ ищи Извлечение всех данных чуть ниже есть получение данных с условием

Comment: Осталась ошибка. on_startup() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given